# Remove all attributes except href and target (if target != '') from all anchor tags

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I have a html string and needs to remove all anchor tag's attribute except href and target ( if target has a valid value ).

```
$content = '<p style="abc" rel="blah blah"> Hello I am p </p> <a href="https://example.com/abc" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"></a>';
```

I have created a regex for the same -

```
preg_replace('/<a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"[^>]*>/', '<a href="\1">', $content)
```

But this remove target attribute as well even though it has valid value ( _blank ).

For example -

```
<a href="https://example.com/abc" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"></a>
```

should return

```
<a href="https://example.com/abc" target="_blank"></a>
```

AND

```
<a href="https://example.com/abc" target="" rel="noopener noreferrer"></a>
```

should return

```
<a href="https://example.com/abc"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following regex:

```
preg_replace('/(\s?target=(?:""))?(\srel.+")\s?/', ' ', $content)
```

I only tested with the two examples you have provided, if not working for some patterns please share some examples.

note: [Online demo for testing](https://regex101.com/r/euge7W/1)

Comment: Thanks for the response. It helped me !

Answer (score 0):

You can take a different approach. Like extract only the `target` attribute and the element content then create a new element with them.

```
$content   = '<a href="https://example.com/abc" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">click here</a>';

// Extract the content.

$value     = array();
$has_value = preg_match( '/<[^<>]+>([^<>]*)<\/[^<>]+>/', $content, $value );

if ( $has_value ) {
    $value = $value[1];
} else {
    $value = '';
}

// Extract the target attribute.

$target_attr = array();
$has_target  = preg_match( '/[\s<]target="[^"]+"[\s>]/', $content, $target_attr );

if ( $has_target ) {
    $target_attr = $target_attr[0];
} else {
    $target_attr = '';
}

$new_content = "<a $target_attr>$value</a>";
```

Output:

```
<a  target="_blank" >click here</a>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the alternative but found the quick workaround.